# Need OBIEE formula to join different lines on the same table

Tags: oracle, formula, obiee

Trying to help a friend here,

Need to create a OBIEE formula to join different lines on the same table over a semi-common OrderId. Here is the source table,

```
OrderId    | Flag  | SKU
-----------|-------|----
order1     |  1    | abc
order1_ex  | -1    | cde
order2     |  1    | xyz
order2_ex  | -1    | tuv
```

And I want something like this as output.

```
OrderId   | SKU1  | SKU-1
----------|-------|------
order1    | abc   | cde
order2    | xyz   | tuv
```

I can think in SQL terms and my solution to this would be to select 1, and -1 flags into two different views and join them by OrderId in a third query to create the expected result set. But I'm helpless with OBIEE formula language. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

That's the wrongest conceivable way to approach this. OBIEE is not SQL Developer with a GUI. It works with models, not queries. You either solve this in the RPD but even better in the ETL before even getting to OBIEE. Never ever in the front-end.

Comment: thanks for the direction. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Can you maybe point me some documents regarding to your suggestions?

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/bi/bi1113/biadmin11g_01/biadmin11g.htm